# .NET MVC trouble laying out images with a delete tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to lay out a group of images in a table format with using div's.  I have an image and then I want to put a Delete link underneath the image.  But I can't get it to layout correctly.  This is what I have:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="imagetiles">
            <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImageURL)" alt="" width="30%" height="30%" />

            <a>Delete</a>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

My styles look like this, I copied it from the Fiddler mentioned in the comments below.  The Fiddler works, but when I apply it, it doesn't work.

```
    div.container {
    width:100%;
}
div.imagetiles {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
div.imagetiles a {
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Below is how this renders.  I want this to put the images next to each other with up to 3 per line.  Why doesn't the Fiddler work for this here?  Why is the imagetile div so big, I can't reduce it to fit the image?

[image]

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vfV7U/ ?

Comment: Almost.  The delete is being rendered correctly, but the images are only 1 column instead of 3.  I had to add width: 30%; to the "div.imagetiles a" css.  I have the width/height of the img tag set at 30%, is that making a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want three per row, I would set the image container (not the main one) to be 33% and then make the width of each image to control the spacing around it (kind of like padding).  Something like this:

```
div.container {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;  /* make sure there is no padding or margin on container */
    padding:0;
}
div.container div.imagetiles {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    padding:0;
}
div.container div.imagetiles img {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 10px;
}
div.imagetiles a {
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2V6/

If you are using something like LESS (recommend or SASS):

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0; padding:0;

    div.imagetiles {
      float:left;
      width: 100%;
      padding:0;

      img {
         width: 95%;
         margin:10px;
      }

      a {
        display:block;
        text-align:right;
        width: 100%;  /* may need to tweak this */
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are small things we need to maintain when `display` is not defined.

Also we need to analyze the `position:` property of element that plays big role in this.

After adding the above I have added z-index to the element and that did it!!.

Have a look at this [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/vfV7U/1/)

CSS:

```
div.container {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
div.imagetiles {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 5px;
    float:left;
}
div.imagetiles img{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1;
}
div.imagetiles a {
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    top:-25px;
    left:-50px;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Nope same result as what I showed with the screenshot above with the exception that the Delete link is way to the right.  The "imagetiles" div still takes up the same space as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

your Implementation is all right. you just need to add width of imagetiles 
like:

`div.imagetiles {
    display:inline-block;
width:30%;
    margin:10px;
}`

It will work like a charm :)